# EF: ArgumentException: Parameter value '100,0000000000000000' is out of range

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

(I use Database first and EF6)

My SqlServer column type:

```
Amount As decimal(16, 2)
```

When I try to insert a row like:

```
MyTable table = New MyTable With {
    .ID = Guid.NewGuid(),  
    .Amount = 100D
};

dbContext.MyTable.Add(table);
```

When I submit changes, I get this error:

```
ArgumentException: Parameter value '100,0000000000000000' is out of range.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Update:

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: That's not a SQL or EF error. Post the actual full exception text. The localized string format (`100,000` instead of `100.000`)` suggests some application code is using that value, maybe even converting it to a localized string. Perhaps an interceptor?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ... I use DevArt to genereate EF POCO classes - maybe it's an errormessage in their tools. I will try to contact them. I have update the post with a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Isn't the problem that it shuld be "100.0000000000000000" (dot) instead of "100,0000000000000000" (comma)?

Comment: That's not the full exception. Click on `Copy Details` and post the full exception text in the question *as text*. Which database are you using and which EF provider? If both the class property and database column are numeric, the value should never be converted to a string. Unless you're using a database that doesn't support query parameters. SQL Server certainly doesn't have such a problem